# Package system is broken (16.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, chromium, ffmpeg

I encountered a package management failure, and I don't know how to troubleshoot it. I have tried `sudo apt -f install` many times, but this errors remains. I have also tried `sudo apt autoremove`; `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt-get clean`; yet the error persists. Is there any way to fix this error?

Here is the error message for `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... failed. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
chromium-browser : Depends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (=56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268)  
 but 57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276 is installed or
 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg (= 56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268) but it is not installed   
chromium-browser-l10n : Depends: chromium-browser (>=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276)  
 but 56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268 is installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be 
caused by held packages. 

E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Output of `apt policy chromium-browser` :

```
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268
  Candidate: 57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276
  Version table:
57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276 500
        500 http: //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
***56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Results of `sudo apt install chromium-browser=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:16.04.5) but 1:16.04.6 is to be installed
update-manager-core : Depends: python3-update-manager (= 1:16.04.6) but 1:16.04.5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy chromium-browser`.

Comment: @fkraiem: please see the update. i've tweaked the format a little bit, but the contents are the same because they don't allow more than 2 links in the post for low-reputation user like me... many thanks!

Comment: Your version of `chromium-browser` is not the latest one; try `sudo apt upgrade`, and if that doesn't work do `sudo apt install chromium-browser=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276` to get a clue as to why the package can't be upgraded.

Comment: @fkraiem i've added the outputs of  `sudo apt install chromium-browser=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276` to the questions. i have another broken package `update-manager-core`

Comment: Your version of `update-manager` is also behind, again you need to try to manually install the latest version to see what is preventing the upgrade...

Comment: i've come to a point of totally stuck between not able to install anything and not able to uninstall anything. is there anything i can do manually before resetting the whole OS?

Comment: The only thing you can do it to repeatedly try to install the newest versions of packages until finally you find the core reason which prevents upgrades from going through. When you have found and fixed it, everything will fall back into place nicely, but finding it may be tedious.

Comment: it boils down to several options, which include 3 packages that i didn't have a chance to update during the last few days.

`sudo apt install update-manager=1.16.04.6`
`sudo apt install update-manager-core=1:16.04.6`
`sudo apt install python3-update-manager=1:16.04.6`
`sudo apt install chromium-browser=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276`

can i uninstall chromium manually? because the other 2 or 3 seems to be more important...

Comment: You need to upgrade them all at once: `sudo apt install package1=version1 package2=version2 ...`.

Comment: OMG that works!!! i was able to trace down the problem by adding the packages sequentially. somehow it starts falling into places.  tremendous thanks to you!! sorry i can't vote up your comment because the low rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error message like this one

> chromium-browser : Depends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (=
>   56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.04.1268) but 57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276 > is installed

must be interpreted as "your version of `chromium-browser` depends on an old version of `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`". The most likely cause is that the upgrade of `chromium-browser` failed for some reason, and indeed `apt-cache policy chromium-browser` confirms that the installed version is not the newest one available. This is a problem because in principle **all the packages installed on a system must always be at their latest version**.

Thus we must upgrade `chromium-browser` to its latest version, which as per `apt-cache policy` is `57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276`. One way to do this is to run `sudo apt install chromium-browser=57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1276`.

Sadly, this did not work because some other packages exhibited the same issue; they must also be manually upgraded by appending them to the `apt install` command (as opposed to by a separate command) until all out-of-date packages are accounted for.